# How can one do parallel actions in OpenWhisk?

Tags: openwhisk

I have two actions (each one does a different REST call to a service to collect some data), and I want to create a meta-Action which essentially triggers the two actions and aggregates the results.

I am just getting started with OpenWhisk, And I pretty much know how I would do this in the given language I am using to implement actions, but I am curious what the appropriate OpenWhisk way to do this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to aggregate the results, there is no other way currently than the one described by you:

Create a new action, fire the two actions (blocking=true) and merge the results.

The [`openwhisk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openwhisk#invoke-action) module on npm makes that extra-simple, as you can invoke an array of actions there:

```
var openwhisk = require("openwhisk")
function main(params) {
    var ow = openwhisk()
    return ow.actions.invoke([
        {name: "action1", blocking: true}, 
        {name: "action2", blocking: true}
    ]).then(([result1, result2]) => { /* do something */ });
}
```

Invoking the actions `blocking`ly, makes their results available in the response vs. not using `blocking` where you'll only get an activation id to get the results in an asynchronous fashion.

Comment: Oh cool. That's exactly what I was looking for. Are the actions basically run in parallel? How is a timeout handled?

Comment: Yes, they are run in parallel. A blocking invocation will return the result of the computation for up to 60 seconds. After that, it'll fall back to a non-blocking activation, handing you the activation id as described above. So for the above code to be meaningful, your actions need to pass in < 60 seconds or you'll need to poll for the result in the "do something" block.