# OpenWhisk parallel execution

Tags: openwhisk

I tried the code from this answer [Parallel Actions in OpenWhisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859812/how-can-one-do-parallel-actions-in-openwhisk/53141892#53141892)

But instead of getting the result, i only get back the activationID. It seems that the actions are not blocking when invoking an array of actions?

Comment: Double check that the action invocation is not taking longer that 60 seconds it will be converted to async invoke and respond with the activation id

Comment: It was a really simple function, and i checked immediately with the activation id the result. i'm sure that it hasn't took longer than 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The calls to "action1, action2", in the code, which you have linked to, are done blocking. However, that does not affect the way you call the action itself. To call it blocking, use

```
wsk action invoke <action-name>  -b
```

This will give you a lot of output. You can reduce it by filtering to the result only

```
wsk action invoke <action-name> -br
```